# Proving that this relation implies another relation on the Coxeter group [4,3,3,4].

Tags: group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory, coxeter-groups

I have a group with five generators $\sigma_i$, and the following relations:

\begin{split}
\sigma_i^2 = \varepsilon \\
|i-j| \neq 1 \implies (\sigma_i\sigma_j)^2 = \varepsilon \\
(\sigma_0\sigma_1)^4 = \varepsilon \\
(\sigma_1\sigma_2)^3 = \varepsilon \\
(\sigma_2\sigma_3)^3 = \varepsilon \\
(\sigma_3\sigma_4)^4 = \varepsilon \\
(\sigma_0\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_3\sigma_4\sigma_3\sigma_2\sigma_1)^n = \varepsilon \\
\end{split}

Note that without the last relation this is the Coxeter group $[4,3,3,4]$. So we can think of this as the Coxeter group $[4,3,3,4]$ with an extra relation. Equivalently this is $I_2(n)\wr S_4$.

The task is to prove:

$$
(\sigma_0\sigma_4\sigma_1\sigma_3\sigma_2\sigma_1\sigma_3)^{2n} = \varepsilon
$$

or equivalently, that the group $\left\langle\sigma_0\sigma_4,\sigma_1\sigma_3,\sigma_2\right\rangle$ is isomorphic to $I_2(n)\wr S_3$.

### Why do I believe this could be true?

I've use the GAP system to confirm that this is true for $n < 16$. While always finite some of these groups begin to get very large, so I think it's very likely this holds for all $n$.

### What have I done so far?

Besides confirming it holds for cases, I've tried a couple of approaches.

- The first was to simply hope that $\sigma_0\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_3\sigma_4\sigma_3\sigma_2\sigma_1 = (\sigma_0\sigma_4\sigma_1\sigma_3\sigma_2\sigma_1\sigma_3)^2$ as if I could prove that, it would solve the problem. It turns out that is not the case.
- Next I hoped that $\sigma_0\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_3\sigma_4\sigma_3\sigma_2\sigma_1$ and $(\sigma_0\sigma_4\sigma_1\sigma_3\sigma_2\sigma_1\sigma_3)^2$ were conjugates in $[4,3,3,4]$, since conjugates have the same order in a group. GAP can solve for this and it found they were in fact not conjugates.
- [Jykri Lahtonen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11619/jyrki-lahtonen) pointed out that outer automorphisms preserve order, so I could in addition checking the two values are in the same conjugacy class I could check if applying the dual automorphism to one of the values makes it the conjugate of the other. So if I could show $\sigma_4\sigma_3\sigma_2\sigma_1\sigma_0\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_3$ and $(\sigma_0\sigma_4\sigma_1\sigma_3\sigma_2\sigma_1\sigma_3)^2$ are conjugates this would also prove the result. However GAP tells me these are not conjugates either.

### Where does this problem come from?

This problem sort of looks like random nonsense. Just something made from bashing together random generators until something stuck. However it is part of a larger problem which I will try to briefly justify here.

The Coxeter group $[4,3,3,4]$ corresponds to the symmetry of the 5-dimensional hypercubic honeycomb, and the additional relation that we give gives a subsymmetry of the 4-torus in 8-dimensional Euclidean space. The 4-torus being a quotient of 4-space.

The relation I am aiming to prove shows that this symmetry has a nice relationship to similar symmetries of the 2-torus in 4-space.

This relationship is useful to me for proving that certain types of polyhedral embeddings exist in 8-space.

Comment: I don't have GAP so cannot test. But would it help, if you combine your other ideas with the use of the outer automorphism that interchanges $\sigma_0\leftrightarrow\sigma_4$, $\sigma_1\leftrightarrow\sigma_3$ and keeps $\sigma_2$ fixed? An outer automorphism also preserves orders.

Comment: What I had in mind was that $x$ and all conjugates $g\phi(x)g^{-1}$ of $\phi(x)$ still have the same order because $x$ and $\phi(x)$ do.  Apply the outer automorphism to one element but not to the other. Unlikely to help, but...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ah I see, that makes more sense.  Also doesn't work unfortunately, but thanks.

Comment: Unsure whether this helps, but your element of putative order $2n$ is equivalent to $abcedcb$ using the Coxeter relations.